# frequency of letters in column python

Tags: python, frequency

I want to calculate the frequency of occurrence of  each  letter in all columns:
for example I have this three sequences :

```
seq1=AATC
seq2=GCCT
seq3=ATCA
```

here, we have: in the first column frequency of 'A' is 2 , 'G' is 1 .
for the second column : the frequency of 'A' is 1, 'C' is 1 and  'T' is 1. (the same thing in the rest of column)
first, I try to do the code of calculating frequency I try this:

for example:

```
s='AATC'

dic={}
for x in s:
    dic[x]=s.count(x)
```

this gives: `{'A':2,'T':1,'C':1}`
now, I want to apply this on columns.for that I use this instruction:

```
f=list(zip(seq1,seq2,seq3))
```

gives:

```
[('A', 'G', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'T'), ('T', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'T', 'A')]
```

So, here, I calculate the frequency of letters in ():
How can I do this ?

if I work on a file of sequences, how can I use this code to apply it on the sequences of file?
for example my file contains 100 sequences each time I take three sequences and apply this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with my answer to your last question, you should wrap your functionality in a function:

```
def lettercount(pos):
    return {c: pos.count(c) for c in pos}
```

Then you can easily apply it to the tuples from `zip`:

```
counts = [lettercount(t) for t in zip(seq1, seq2, seq3)]
```

Or combine it into the existing loop:

```
...
counts = []
for position in zip(seq1, seq2, seq3): # sets at same position
    counts.append(lettercount(position))
    for pair in combinations(position, 2): # pairs within set
        ...
```

Comment: OK, thank you.Now, I want to calculate the entropy of this sequences.entropy=p_0 * log p_0+p_1 * log p_1+...+p_n* log p_n. p is the frequency of letter x in a given column. (this is the entropy for one column). for example entropy of first column  ({'A': 2, 'G': 1})is 2/3 log(2/3)+1/3 log(1/3)

Comment: You can tackle that yourself. Create a function `def entropy(count):` and read through [the `math` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions). Also, note that two people have spent their time writing helpful answers and you haven't even up-voted either of them: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
sequences = ['AATC',
             'GCCT',
             'ATCA']
f = zip(*sequences)
counts = [{letter: column.count(letter) for letter in column} for column in f]
print(counts)
```

Output (reformatted):

```
[{'A': 2, 'G': 1}, 
 {'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'T': 1}, 
 {'C': 2, 'T': 1}, 
 {'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'T': 1}]
```

Salient features:

- Rather than explicitly naming `seq1`, `seq2`, etc., we put them into a list.
- We unpack the list with the `*` operator.
- We use a dict comprehension inside a list comprehension to generate the counts for each letter in each column. It's basically what you did for the one-sequence case, but more readable (IMO).