# Entropy of sequences

Tags: python, sequences, entropy

Can some help me to rectify my code?
I have 3 sequences

```
 seq1='AATC'
 seq2='GCCT'
 seq3='ATCA'
```

I want to calculate the entropy of three sequences, its formula is:

```
Entropy (A[:][i])= - ∑  p_ia log( p_ia)
p_ia = C_ia /∑  C_ia'
```

where p_ia is the probability of letter a in column i ,and C_ia is the number of letter a in the column A[:][i]

example: from the above 3 sequences: first column:a' take the values C , A and C, here C_ia'= 3 , if a='C' C_ia=2 so p_ia=2 /3,

if a='A' C_ia=1 so p_ia=1 /3

```
Entropy (A[:][0])=-(2/3 log (2/3)+1/3 log(1/3))
```

the same thing for the rest of columns.
I have tried this:
this function calculate the  occurence (frequency) of each letter in a given string and l is the length of string it means `l=∑  C_ia'.`

```
def occ(source):
    occ={}
    l=0
    for e in source:
        l +=1
        if e not in occ:
            occ[e]=0
        occ[e]+=1
    return (l,occ)
```

example:

```
>>> source='aaazzzedc'
>>> occ(source)
(9, {'z': 3, 'c': 1, 'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 1})
```

then, this is the function of entropy:

```
def entropy(occ,l):
    elist=[]
    for v in occ.values():
        c=v/l
        elist.append(-c *math.log(c, 2))
    return sum(elist)
```

example:

```
>>> (l,h)=occ(source)
>>> entropy(h,l)
2.113283334294875
```

OK.
this is for simple example, but for me I want to apply it on columns of sequences.

```
>>> source=[occ(t) for t in zip(seq1,seq2,seq3)]
>>> source
[(3, {'A': 2, 'G': 1}), (3, {'C': 1, 'A': 1, 'T': 1}), (3, {'C': 2, 'T': 1}), (3, {'C': 1, 'A': 1, 'T': 1})]
```

how can I calculate the entropy of this sequences?
this gives by the first column:

```
(3, {'A': 2, 'G': 1})
2/3 * log(2/3)+ 1/3 * log (1/3)
```

How can I write the entropy of all columns?

Comment: What is your problem? You have a function to calculate entropy and ([from previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103320/frequency-of-letters-in-column-python)) you have a structure for iterating through your data. Which part can't you manage?

Comment: for this :[(3, {'A': 2, 'G': 1}), (3, {'C': 1, 'A': 1, 'T': 1}), (3, {'C': 2, 'T': 1}), (3, {'C': 1, 'A': 1, 'T': 1})]. how can I calculate its entropy?

Comment: The code in your question demonstrates that you can iterate using a `for` loop (`for v in occ.values():`), unpack tuples (`(l,h)=occ(source)`) and call functions (`entropy(h,l)`). What else do you need to do?

Comment: OK.I try my code on simple example. source='aaazzzedc', but I dont know how to do for  apply the code on the three sequences.

Comment: *How can you not know how to do it?!* Read my answers to your previous questions. There is already code there that iterates through all the sequences. You just need to insert calls to your `opp` and `entropy` functions into the correct place, and create new lists (e.g. `entropies = []` to hold the results.

Comment: OK.thank you.I try this and it works correctly.`>> entropies=[].
>>> for position in zip(seq1,seq2,seq3):
 (l,h)=occ(position)
 m=entropy(h,l)
entropies.append(m)`

Comment: There you go! Challenge: if you have the arguments to `entropy` in the same order as the return values from `occ`, you can cut three lines to one (`entropies.append(entropy(*occ(position)))` - note the `*`).